# Javascript .each() returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, each, element

When I try to use .each() to do same function to multiple elements on my page it always return var HD as 'undefined'

```js
        function hdurl (videoId) {   
     var videoEl = $('#' + videoId); 
     var HD = videoEl.find( "video" ).attr("HD"); 
     alert('returned ' + HD);
    }
    
    
    hdurl("div_video");
```

```html
<video id="div_video" class="video-js" HD="returned" controls>
<source src="~path~" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: can you create a demo of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your code is not valid JS. It makes sense to not change your code so much so that it becomes totally nonsense.

Comment: [demo on jsfiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/7zrode3o/)

Answer (score 1):

You've got an extra find('video') in there for no reason, you've already selected the video element via your id selector, just change that line to:

```
var HDsrc = videoEl.attr("HD");
```

Updated JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5c5p3orh/1/).

Comment: I figured out it last night. Thanks!